# How to fill a checkbox, and Radiobuttons with FluentLenium?

Tags: checkbox, fluentlenium

I'm testing FluentLenium.

I found  "fill("#sb_form_q").with("FluentLenium");" for input(s).

I want check and uncheck Checkbox.

I want choose a radiobutton in a group.

How to do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to click on the radiobutton that have the id "male" just do something like that :

```
find("#male").click();
```

You could use any of the css selectors to find the element you want (radiobutton or checkbox) and act on it (most of the time by clicking).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element such as:

```
<input type="radio" id="radioButton1">
```

You can use either the Lazy Find Annotation:

```
@Findby(id = "radioButton1")
FluentWebElement radioButton;
```

Or the locators:

```
FluentWebElement radioButton = el("input", with("id").equalTo("radioButton1");
```

I prefer the second method for accuracy since you can add more selectors to ensure you find the exact element you want to, the first for ease-of-use/readability.

Then you can use the FluentWebElement's methods to click and unclick.

```
radioButton.click(); /* Selects   */
radioButton.click()  /* Unselects */
```

You would not use fill method.